# How to select item from drop down list using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a login page. In my test case I am able to login with the credentials but once I have logged in I am trying to select item from drop down list. I have the below code but I am getting an error

```
Select select = (Select) driver.findElement(By.id("Id goes here"));
        select.selectByValue("Value Goes here");
```

I am getting the below error 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Value of Id"}

Note: the URL to login is different than the one on which select box is appearing. Can that be a problem? Is there a way to resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried to find the element using `XPath`?

Comment: Nope. Let me try that.

Comment: Did you try increasing Selenium's implicit wait time or (my preferred approach to diagnose issues like yours) did you just add a sleep before trying to find the element? I could be that your script is trying to find it before it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

What you get is a `NoSuchElementException` when WebDriver cannot find the element based on your selection criteria.

Ensure that the WebElement can be located correctly using `id` or another selector. If the `select` element is inside an `iframe`, you will have to switch to it first using [`driver.switchTo().frame()`] (http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html).

Also, you cannot cast `WebElement` to `Select`.

Use:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("listofnames"));
Select select = new Select(elem);
select.selectByValue("Name1");
```

Comment: I am getting an error Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Value of ID"}

Comment: Share the HTML for the element you are trying to identify, what is the actual id.

Comment: <select id="listofnames">

    <option value="Name1">Name1</option>   <option value="Name2">Name2</option>

</select>

Comment: Note: If got this html using firebug, if I try to view source I am not seeing the html since its coming from a template.

Comment: Yes, firebug is the right way to check. Also check in firebug if the element is within an iframe.

Comment: Nope it is not within an iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
String Xcode =  "//li[@class='dropdown']/a"; //<-your xpath here    
WebElement CourseSelector = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Xcode));
CourseSelector.click();
try {Thread.sleep(3000);} // o&c - GIVES TIME FOR ITEMS TO APPEAR
    catch (InterruptedException wtv)    
    {System.out.println("problem on wait with resource load" + wtv);    } 
Xcode =  "//ul/li/a[text()='" + Your_Menu_Item_Here + "']"; // <- again your xpath here
CourseSelector = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Xcode));
CourseSelector.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Select dropdown1;

```
    dropdown2 = new Select (mozila.findElement(By.id("of the dropdown1"))); 

            dropdown2.selectByValue("9");
```

Select dropdown2;

```
    dropdown2 = new Select (mozila.findElement(By.id("of the dropdown2")));  

    dropdown3.selectByValue("2018");
```